# Guarantee unique datasets in Hibernate JoinTable

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, unique, join

as I am a newbie in Hibernate I read, searched and tried already a lot before coming to this question.

In fact I have one simple table (e.g. Person) with only a generated id and a unique name as second column. A second table (e.g. Users) contains a generated id as well and a Set< Person> of names from table 1.

For the Set< Person > in table 2 I create a @ManyToMany relationship, resulting in a JoinTable. So far so good (works as expected).

What I need now (and am not able to realize) is a way in which I can define, that each of these sets of persons exists only 1 time in the join table (so I don't want to have a same combination of Person A and B twice in the table, but for sure an additional entry for person A or a combi of A and C).

Do you have any suggestions or tips in which direction I need to go from here?